# Can we declare structure object at file scope before the structure definition?

Tags: c

According to the code given below and the answer for it:

> **Question**: Which of the following structure declarations will throw an error?
>
> 1. ```
>    struct temp { char c; } s;
>    int main(void) {}
>    ```
> 2. ```
>    struct temp { char c; };
>    struct temp s;
>    int main(void) {}
>    ```
> 3. ```
>    struct temp s; 
>    struct temp { char c; };
>    int main(void) {}
>    ```
> 4. None of the above.
>
> **Answer**: 4

Is this correct? Can we declare a structure object first and only then the structure definition?

Comment: This looks more like C than C++.

Comment: All the functions shown are non-standard for the whole of the current millennium.   All the structures are malformed. None of the code should compile.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I compiled the third one, all I got was a warning that the type of `main()` was missing, and it defaults to `int`.

Comment: You’re not supposed to be able to compile an empty structure body.  In (c) there is no type `struct temp` when `s` is nominally defined, so the variable shouldn’t be definable.  There might be a get-out-of-jail-free card somewhere; I don’t have a C compiler on my iPhone.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The question is about the order of declarations, the structure members are irrelevant. I added `int main` and a structure member, and it still compiles with no warnings. I also added a body to `main` that accesses the structure member, no complaints. I'm as surprised as the OP.

Comment: I’m asleep. My robot is responding now.  If there’s still a controversy in the morning, I’ll look.   If you ever needed evidence of why multichoice questions are abominable, this illustrates the point.  You can’t present reasoning in an exam.

Comment: @jonathan: [Empty structures are a GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Empty-Structures.html#Empty-Structures) to C.

Comment: @rici: I wondered if there was some GCC-nonsense and `-pedantic` was not in use.  The question wasn't tagged GCC, so GCC extensions should be irrelevant, though the OP may not know about the issue of GCC enthusiastically extending C.  I also wondered whether tentative definitions were a factor, but I was under the illusion that the type had to be complete to declare a variable of the type at the point of declaration.

Comment: @jonathan: as per 6.9.2, only if the variable has internal linkage: "If the declaration of an identifier for an object is a tentative  definition and has internal linkage, the declared type shall not be an incomplete type." You can also use incomplete types as parameter or return types in function declarations which are not definitions.

Answer (score 14):

Yeah, C is weird sometimes. Because that variable is at file scope and has no initializer or storage class specifier, it constitutes a tentative defintion. The C standard defines it as follows:

> **6.9.2 External object definitions**
>
> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope
>   without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with
>   the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a tentative
>   definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative
>   definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no
>   external definition for that identifier, **then the behavior is exactly
>   as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
>   identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation
>   unit**, with an initializer equal to 0.

I emphasized the relevant part. Because there is no initializer on your variable, it's as though you'd written it at the very end of the file and initialized to zero. The physical layout of the file is immaterial, because logically, the definition of the structure type is available at the end of the file.

So the answer is indeed (4). I wouldn't write code like that in real life however, this is terribly confusing in the C eco-system where near everything must be pre-declared to be used.